# Install mixture of extension module. pure python module and shared libraries with distutils

Tags: python, distutils, cython

I am using cython for building an extension module. The module depends on an external shared library, which is found when the module is built. Further I have some pure Python modules in the same directory.

Can anybody give me an example setup.py for this task ? I have problems getting the extension module, the pure python module and the shared lib in the same directory when calling "python setup.py install".

Comment: Are you using Py2EXE for deployment, or just trying to make a binary installer for you package using `python setup.py bdist_wininst`?

Comment: I just tried a local "python setup.py install" to get my stuff to .../site-packages/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: I have a package dir ABC like

```
ABC/
    __init__.py
    A.py
    B.pyx
    C.so             (or C.dll and C.lib on win)
```

then the following setup.py does the job:

```
#input-encoding: utf-8
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

setup(
  name = "ABC",
  packages = ["ABC"],
  package_dir = { "ABC" : "." },
  ext_package = "ABC",
  cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
  package_data = { ".": [ "C.dll"] },
  ext_modules = [ Extension("B", sources="B.pyx", libraries="C" ) ]
)
```

I had to put setup.py in ABC/ and redirect via `package_dir = { "ABC" : "." },`

Comment: > I had to put setup.py in ABC
That sounds strange.  Have you tried with package_data = {'ABC': ['abc/C.dll']} instead?

Comment: tried it, but did not work. Finally I setup a regular dir structure with the package one level below my setup.py.